# How to write sample data in USB flash drive as text file Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am having Ubuntu 20.04 in my computer. I need to know how can I write a sample data in USB flash drive as text file Ubuntu 20.04 ? The USB flash drive is connected to Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

The sample data generation is continuous in a C program like 10 kilo bytes per second.

Comment: basically something like `datagenerator > /mount/point/ofyourUSBdevice/filename` but what are your really detailed needs (please edit your question).

Comment: Does the sample data need to be read later to check for corruption? Do you want to test with kilobytes or gigabytes of data? Is this something you want to automate or do manually? Is this something you’ll do once or a thousand times? Depending on what your ultimate goals are, the answer could be very, very different.

Comment: You must *mount* your flash drive so it shows up in the filesystem. Mounting is often automatic; you have provided insufficient information to determine if your drive is mounted or not. Edit your question to include the complete output of the 'df' command.